# How to create a dotnet gRPC server without using concrete instances

Tags: grpc, grpc-dotnet

So I am trying to build a .Net Core app that has both REST and gRPC.

**Expected results:** To have one app running that supports a working REST on one port and gRPC on another.

REST is easy. It's where the app starts. But to configure gRPC's port I saw I needed to create a Server instance:

```
        Server server = new Server
        {
            Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterImpl()) }
            Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", 5001, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
        };

        server.Start();
```

That's all fine until we actually put it to use and like any other "Controller" GreeterImpl needs Dependency Injection of services:

```
        private readonly IExampleService _exampleService;

        public GreeterImpl (IExampleService exampleService)
        {
            _exampleService = exampleService;
        }
```

Now the first code snippet will not work since the "new GreeterImpl()" requires an IExampleService.
I searched the web on how to get a ServerServiceDefinition (the thing returned from Greeter.BindService() ) without the use of concrete implementations but found nothing. So, how should this be done or am I on a totally wrong path?

Comment: Assuming you're using ASP.NET Core for your REST APIs, it is easier to use the [gRPC implementation that builds upon ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet). This way you end up sharing the same app func and service container across both gRPC and REST with them merely being different endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was going at it with the wrong idea. Turns our you can use

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof({YOUR_SERVICE}))
```

Where "app" is "IApplicationBuilder"
And then just use the resulting service in the ".BindService()". 
In the end we don't change the ".BindService()" but pass it a working service to bind.

Important note: You have to register your service first. In my case I used AutoFac to register it